# Retrieve value from option html tag and pass to another servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, select

Let say I have two servlet called servlet1 and servlet2.

Servet1

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    ...
    String htmlFormat = "<h2>Choose a employee</h2>" + "<p>Employee Name: <select name=\"employeeName\" onchange=\"location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\">";

    for (Employee employee: employees) {
        htmlFormat += "<option value=\"servlet2\">" + employee.getFirstName() + " " + employee.getLastName() + "</option>";
    }

    htmlFormat += "</select></p>";
    out.print(htmlFormat);     

}
```

As you can see, when i click on the one of the option, it lead me to a servlet2. I would like to know do i pass user's click option (employee first name + last name ) value to another servlet. I need to get the firstname and lastname on the servlet2. Please help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first servlet, have it output an html form that will POST the formdata back to the server:

```
<form id="usersubmit" action="servlet2"></form>
```

Make your selectbox part of the formdata. If you want the form to be submitted onchange you can use javascript:

```
<select name="employeeName" form="usersubmit" onchange="this.form.submit()">
...
</select>
```

Lastly the `value` attribute of each `<option>` tag should contain the values you wish to send/retrieve, so in your servlet you can write:

```
htmlFormat += "<option value=\" " +employee.getFirstName()+ " " +employee.getLastName()+ " \">" + employee.getFirstName() + " " + employee.getLastName() + "</option>";
```

This should send the value of the selected `option` to "servlet2". To access the value in servlet2 use:

```
request.getParameter("employeeName");
```

Answer (score 1):

This action takes place on the client, not the server. You need to POST the HTML form back to the server and access the `employeeName` field from the FORMDATA.

Comment: How should i post option tag text without a button to submit it? The moment i click one of option, i had been lead to the servlet2...

Comment: I don't know Java, but the technique is valid for all web form handling. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228571/display-form-processing-results-on-current-page-in-jsp

Comment: @user2850163, get rid of the onChange method and give your form a submit button. Of course then you'd have to actually make a `<form>`.